# Chrome Extension Debugging: Enter Debugger Immediately?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

If I set breakpoints in the background js of my chromium extension, then disable/enable it, the breakpoints are not hit.  I've tried adding `debugger;` in the js, but I still cannot enter the debugger.

Is there a way to enter the debugger immediately upon installing or enabling an extension?

Answer (score 3):

Add the `debugger;` statements, and inspect your background page. Then, use `F5` (or `location.reload()` from the console) to refresh the Developer Tools. This will actually refresh the background page, letting you debug the page from the top.

Note: this will not work for "first run" code, but will for "start up" code.